# variable para agregar hora

Tags: python, odoo

Estoy buscando una variable para agregar una hora de inicio y de termino en sus respectivas casillas. Actualmente estoy usando `fields.Datetime` pero con ello me hace elegir fecha y solo quiero agregar un campo para agregar solo la hora. Me podrían ayudar por favor.

```
class reserva (models.Model):

     _name='gimnasio.reserva'

     tipo_reserva=fields.Selection([('0','Clase'),('1','Evaluacion')])

     fecha_reserva=fields.Date()

     hora_inicio=fields.Datetime()

     hora_termino=fields.Datetime()
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar la librería datetime

```
import datetime
hora = datetime.datetime.now().time()
print type(hora)
print hora

<type 'datetime.time'>
14:42:11.172000
```